# PowerShell Remoting - Certificate Authentication

Tags: powershell

I am trying to remote to a different server using certificate authentication - this was previously working.

However I now get this error when I try to connect:
*An attempt has been made to operate on an
impersonation token by a thread that is not currently impersonating a client*

Any ideas on what would be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

This was due to the following security setting be applied to the account used for Certificate Authentication.

"Deny access to this computer from the network"